# Is it possible to read and parse csv in streaming mode with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to download huge CSV and parse it line by line in streaming mode. My code is:

```
with httpx.stream("GET", url) as r:
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        for row in csv.reader([line]):
            ...
```

but if there are "multi-lines" in input file this code doesn't work.

```
col11,col12,col13
col21,"co
l22", col23
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Offhand I would call that malformed data ... on the surface it looks like csv, but it isn't (which means this isn't a question about reading csv anymore). Why is it like that?

Comment: No, this is normal CSV file with line breaks in text fields

Comment: ah I see. Yes I generally just treat csv with line breaks as a "bad thing" and don't allow it. I forgot its my own rule, not a csv rule.

Comment: `for row in csv.reader([line]):` No! Why are you doing that's `csv.reader` expects an iterable of lines. Just pass it the iterator

Comment: @topsail it's fine if the line breaks are quoted. And the `xsv` model would have handled it correctly if it had been used correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`r.iter_lines()` is an iterator over lines of text, just as a file is.

So if you can pass a file to `csv.reader`, you can pass `r.iter_lines()` as well.

```
with httpx.stream("GET", url) as r:
    for row in csv.reader(r.iter_lines()):
        ...
```